# How can I resolve this syntax error in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, trading, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to get my code to work, but I have the following error:
"Error at 21:0 Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'."
I have tried everything, but nothing works, does anyone know what the problem could be? I leave my code below:

```
var xATRTrailingStop = 0.0
var entry_price = 0.0
var win_condition_met = false
var loss_condition_met = false

xATRTrailingStop := iff(src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src - nLoss),
    iff(src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src + nLoss),
        iff(src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), src - nLoss, src + nLoss)))

pos = 0
```

Any information you could give me would help me a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: Please can you add a screenshot of this part of code with the relative lines.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your log says "Error on line 21", but you only post 10 lines
2. The original code can be seen here:
   https://tradingview.com/script/kMtzYo7p-Average-True-Range-Trailing-Stops-Strategy/
3. An indexing error may occur during conversion to v3
   Try this:

```
xATRTrailingStop :=  iff(src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src - nLoss),
                     iff(src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src + nLoss),
                     iff(src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), src - nLoss, src + nLoss)))
```